# ArangoDB Query with multiple OR?

Tags: arangodb

I am using the ArangoDB java driver and am trying to query for documents containing one of a number of Strings, which are stored in the arangoDB documents in lists. I am using ArrayList with a list of Strings in the query.

```
Query:

FOR document IN documents FILTER ( @now - document.dateAdded < 2592000000 ) && 
(document.categories IN @categories || document.tags IN @tags 
|| document.locations IN @locations ) RETURN document

Map<String, Object> bindVars = new MapBuilder().put("now", now).put("categories", categories).put("@tags", tags).put("@locations", locations).get();
```

"now" contains a long. All the others are `ArrayList<String>.` This is throwing an error explaining that "`bind parameter '@tags' has an invalid value or type`". Since this ArrayList is no different than the others, my only theory is that I am inputting the logic incorrectly. How does one query for:

```
FunctionCondition1 AND (condition2 OR condition3 OR condition4)
```

Comment: Can you try the following: bindVars = new MapBuilder().put("now", now).put("categories", categories).put("tags", tags).put("locations", locations).get();

Comment: The bind vars are marked in the query using "@", but the are given without the first '@'. A collection parameter is specified with two at as "@@myvariablecollection'. In the case the bind var is '@myvariablecollection' and must be of type collection.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, can you post a quick answer so that I may give you proper credit?

Comment: @Jgolden1 can you also check this answer as accepted? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The bind vars are marked in the query using `'@'`, but they are given without the first `'@'`. A collection parameter is specified with two at symbols `@@` as `@@myvariablecollection`. In this case the bind var is `@myvariablecollection` and must be of type collection.

For example:

```
FOR a IN @@collection FILTER a.x == @now RETURN a
```

requires the bind variables to be given as `@collection` and `now` where `@collection` must name a collection and `now` should be (in this example) a number.

```
Map<String, Object> bindVars = new MapBuilder().put("@collection", "myCollection").put("now", 1234).get();
```